# Is there a way to replace null values with values from another column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with dataframe with many missing values. Iam looking for efficient way to replace the missing values. Following is the example of the dataframe:

```
s/n     Name      Home_Zip      work_zip        Family_zip
 1      John      56729         N/A             836AB
 2      sawn      N/A           N/A             73836
 3      Michael   N/A          839CD            83093
 4      Nathan    93932        78393            N/a
 5      Jack      N/A          N/A              N/A
```

Here, I want to fill missing values in `Home_Zip` in a way that it looks first in `work_zip` if it is
not null returns that value else it returns the `family_zip`. If in the case of all the value
are null it returns unknown.

```
 s/n     Name      Home_Zip     work_zip        Family_zip
 1      John      56729         N/A              836AB
 2      sawn      73836         N/A              73836
 3      Michael   839CD         839CD            83093
 4      Nathan    93932         78393            N/a
 5      Jack      Unkown        N/A             N/A
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bfill` followed by `fillna()`.

```
df['Home_Zip'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].bfill(1).fillna('Unknown')['Home_Zip']
```

Or chain several `fillna`:

```
df['Home_Zip'] = (df['Home_Zip'].fillna(df['work_zip'])
                     .fillna(df['Family_zip'])
                     .fillna('Unknown')
                 )
```

Output:

```
   s/n     Name Home_Zip work_zip Family_zip
0    1     John    56729      NaN      836AB
1    2     sawn    73836      NaN      73836
2    3  Michael    839CD    839CD      83093
3    4   Nathan    93932    78393        N/a
4    5     Jack  Unknown      NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Perfecto this is exactly what i was looking for. Thankyou.

Comment: is there way to control the number of columns to look for in bffill.

Comment: Yes, you can replace `df.iloc[:,2:]` by `df[your_column_list]`.